# Iterating feature classes in multiple geodatabases using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I have 5 geodatabases. All have a feature dataset that contains a point feature class called "Point" and a line feature class called "Polyline." I want to go through these feature datasets, take only the Polyline feature class and append it to a master feature class.

Is there a way to nest iterators?

I tried created submodels, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

A Quick Model to demonstrate nested iteration:

For this cocktail, you're going to need 5 Input GeoDatabases(or more if you like), and 1 Output GeoDatabase. The Input_GDB's should have some Feature Datasets that contain some Feature Classes. The Output_GDB only requires a Feature Dataset.

A workspace similar to this:

[image: Workspace Layout]

We are going to need 8 Models(seen in the Contents Tab and the StackExchange Toolbox under the Catalog Tree) for this solution:

1. Combine_To_Master
2. Create_Combine_Target
3. Iterate_Feature_Classes
4. Iterate_Datasets
5. Iterate_Workspaces
6. Append_Feature_Classes
7. Append_Datasets
8. Append_Workspaces

Combine_To_Master drives the whole process with parameters for:

1. Input Folder           (folder named Iterate_GDBs in this example)
2. Workspace_Wildcard     (filter applied to GDB names in the Workspace Folder)
3. Dataset_Wildcard       (filter applied to Dataset names in each GDB)
4. FeatureClass_Wildcard  (filter applied to Feature Class names in each Dataset)
5. FeatureType            (filter applied to Feature Class Iterator for geometry type isolation)
6. OUTPUT_Master_Feature_Dataset (Full Path to a pre-existing Dataset within the OUTPUT GDB)
7. OUTPUT_Master_Feature_Class   (String name used to generate target feature class in OUTPUT_Master_Feature_Dataset)* This name must be unique within the OUTPUT_Master_Feature_Dataset and NOT pre-Exist as this tool will NOT overite an existing OUTPUT_Master_Feature_Class.

Here's the UI:
[image: Combine To Master UI]
and the Model:
[image: Combine_To_Master Model]

It contains 2 sub-models:

1. Create Combine Target  (generates OUTPUT_Master_Feature_Class using schema from first valid feature class)
2. Append Workspaces      (copies valid features to OUTPUT_Master_Feature_Class)

Create_Combine_Target iterates into the workspace to find the first valid Feature Class and uses that Feature Class as a template to create the OUTPUT_Master_Feature_Class schema in the Output_GDB Feature Dataset.

Append_Workspaces iterates over all the filtered workspaces,datasets,and feature classes and appends the valid feature classes to the OUTPUT_Master_Feature_Class created in the previous step.

The Create_Combine_Target Model looks like:
[image: Create Combine Target Model]
It contains sub-model Iterate_Workspaces and the built-in Create_Feature_Class Tool.

The important part here is that sub-model Iterate_Workspaces will call Iterate_Datasets which will call Iterate_FeatureClasses which will return the first valid feature class AND a boolean, FC_Found, as a pre-condition to the built-in Create_Feature_Class Tool. Additionally, it will set the Stop Flag to avoid unnecessary iteration after the first valid feature class has been found.

If we look at the Iterate_Workspaces model we will start to see how the iterators chain into this process definiton.
[image: Iterate Workspaces Model]
This model sets up the Workspace iterator to feed workspaces from the Iterate_GDB's folder filtered by the Workspaces_Wildcard into the Iterate_Datasets sub-model.

The Iterate_Datasets Model looks like:
[image: Iterate Datasets Model]
This model is similar to Iterate_Workspaces except it feeds datasets from valid workspaces filtered by Dataset_Wildcard into the Iterate_Feature_Classes sub-model.

And the Iterate_FeatureClasses Model looks like:
[image: Iterate FeatureClasses Model]
The only unique thing about this model is the Calculate Tool used to insepect the Feature_Class_Name in order to set the Stop Flag once a valid feature class has been found.

Claculate Tool Expression:

```
fc_found(r"%Feature_Class_Name%")
```

Calculate Tool Code Block:

```
def fc_found(fc_name):
  if len(fc_name)>0:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Calculate Tool Datatype:

```
Boolean
```

Once a valid feature class has been found, the Stop Flag will be set, FC_Found will be set to True, the feature class and FC_Found will be returned to the Iterate_Datasets Model.

The Iterate_Datasets Model will set its Stop Flag and return the feature class, along with FC_Found, to Iterate_Workspaces.

The Iterate_Workspaces Model will set its Stop Flag and return the feature class, along with FC_Found, to Create_Combine_Target.

The Create_Combine_Target Model will set its Stop Flag and pass the feature class to the built-in Create_Feature_Class Tool.

The Create_Feature_Class tool will generate the TARGET_FEATURE_CLASS and return it to Combine_To_Master.

The Combine_To_Master Model will pass the newly created feature class on to Append_Workspaces as the TARGET_DATASET parameter.

The Append_Workspaces Model looks like:
[image: Append Workspaces Model]
This model sets up a new Workspace iterator to feed workspaces from the Iterate_GDB's folder filtered by the Workspaces_Wildcard into the Append_Datasets sub-model.

The Append_Datasets Model looks like:
[image: Append Datasets Model]
This model is similar to Append_Workspaces except it feeds datasets from valid workspaces filtered by Dataset_Wildcard into the Append_Feature_Classes sub-model.

The Append_Feature_Classes Model looks like:
[image: Append Feature Classes Model]
This model is where the GLORIOUS MAGIC happens! Every feature class furnished by the iterator (filterd by Folder/GDB Name/Dataset Name/FeatureClass Name/FeatureType) is Appended to the TARGET_DATASET (which is really holding the OUTPUT_Master_Feature_Class!!)

Here's some sample maps that show the input / and output feature classes after execution of the Model.

Input Map:
[image: Map INPUT Layers]
Output Map:
[image: Map OUTPUT Layers]

For anyone who is brave enough and still reading this, here are the:

[Models and Sample GDB's](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/is1ckpanu2ucf5b/AADat4-IBLSxIPNX-64W45v1a?dl=0)

*Future Plans for this tool include, TimeStamping and Source Documenting the features as they are loaded into OUTPUT_Master_Feature_Class. Source Documenting will be spread across 4 columns named SOURCE_PATH, SOURCE_GDB, SOURCE_DATASET, and SOURCE_FEATURE_CLASS to allow for some interesting post-analysis.

Comment: Wow impressive, I am interested to have the toolbox and example data. Would you mind to put it in dropbox or other cloud storage please?